# how to use pythran add a myfunction from other py files?

Tags: python, pythran

##### toolsTep.py

```py
def HelloWord():
    print('hello word')
```

##### testpythran.py

```py
from calaTools.toolsTep import *
#pythran export callOtherPyFiles()
def callOtherPyFiles():
    HelloWord()
```

##### complie pythran testpythran.py

- **CRITICAL** :
  I am in trouble. Your input file does not seem to match Pythran's constraints...
- testpythran.py:

  > None:None error: Module 'calaTools.toolsTep' not found.

##### when two function in save file and it can find ,in diffrent file it occured those errors

Comment: How is this c++ related?

Comment: emmm,sorry.it has a little related.but error is not c++.when use pythran,it will get c++ decent binary.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as there isn't an attempt to explain the question.

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it origin use is simple .and i add some comment now.

Answer (score 0):

When distributing a Python application with Pythran modules, you can either:

declare the module as a regular Python module. After all, they are 100% Python compatible.

declare them as a PythranExtension and Pythran will compile them:

from distutils.core import setup

These two lines are required to be able to use pythran in the setup.py
import setuptools
setuptools.dist.Distribution(dict(setup_requires='pythran'))

from pythran.dist import PythranExtension, PythranBuildExt
setup(...,
ext_modules=[PythranExtension("mymodule", ["mymodule.py"])],
cmdclass={"build_ext": PythranBuildExt})
PythranBuildExt is optional, but necessary to build extensions with different C++ compilers. It derives from distuil’s build_ext by default, but you can change its base class by using PythranBuildExt[base_cls] instead.

all configuration options supported in .pythranrc can also be passed through the optional config argument, in the form of a list, e.g. config=['compiler.blas=openblas']

from pythran doc.https://pythran.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MANUAL.html